# Azure cosmos db stored procedure not work

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, java-stored-procedures

I'm looking to MSDN how to write a stored procedure in CosmoDB.

I find the following simple example :

```
var helloWorldStoredProc = {
    id: "helloWorld",
    serverScript: function () {
        var context = getContext();
        var response = context.getResponse();

        response.setBody("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

but if i try to execute it in cosmos db I get the following error message:

```
Failed to execute stored procedure helloWorldId for container Measure: {"code":400,"body":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Encountered exception while compiling Javascript. Exception = SyntaxError: Syntax error\\r\\nSource information: line: 1, column: 36, source line:\\r\\n(function __docDbMain() { var fn = var helloWorldStoredProc = {\"]}\r\nActivityId: 21c41459-2e6b-407b-af9b-80c81ef54746, Request URI: /apps/a6f25760-7394-4bfb-bafc-7ea08f3f3f13/services/6574355c-d55b-43fa-b388-b270ebbd4403/partitions/409dd415-cb4d-49f0-9d16-11c07c880ee2/replicas/132070570012201722p/, RequestStats: \r\nRequestStartTime: 2019-07-08T12:28:32.6776283Z, RequestEndTime: 2019-07-08T12:28:32.7176085Z, Number of regions attempted: 1\r\nResponseTime: 2019-07-08T12:28:32.7176085Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://cdb-ms-prod-australiaeast1-fd3.documents.azure.com:14032/apps/a6f25760-7394-4bfb-bafc-7ea08f3f3f13/services/6574355c-d55b-43fa-b388-b270ebbd4403/partitions/409dd415-cb4d-49f0-9d16-11c07c880ee2/replicas/132070570012201722p/, LSN: 7, GlobalCommittedLsn: 7, PartitionKeyRangeId: 0, IsValid: True, StatusCode: 400, SubStatusCode: 65535, RequestCharge: 1.7, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#7, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: StoredProcedure, OperationType: ExecuteJavaScript\r\n, SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.4.0.0"},"headers":{"access-control-allow-credentials":"true","access-control-allow-origin":"https://cosmos.azure.com","content-type":"application/json","lsn":"7","strict-transport-security":"max-age=31536000","x-ms-activity-id":"21c41459-2e6b-407b-af9b-80c81ef54746","x-ms-cosmos-llsn":"7","x-ms-cosmos-quorum-acked-llsn":"7","x-ms-current-replica-set-size":"4","x-ms-current-write-quorum":"3","x-ms-gatewayversion":"version=2.4.0.0","x-ms-global-committed-lsn":"7","x-ms-last-state-change-utc":"Mon, 08 Jul 2019 10:56:52.631 GMT","x-ms-number-of-read-regions":"0","x-ms-quorum-acked-lsn":"7","x-ms-request-charge":"1.7","x-ms-schemaversion":"1.8","x-ms-serviceversion":"version=2.4.0.0","x-ms-session-token":"0:-1#7","x-ms-substatus":"65535","x-ms-transport-request-id":"1","x-ms-xp-role":"1","x-ms-throttle-retry-count":0,"x-ms-throttle-retry-wait-time-ms":0},"activityId":"21c41459-2e6b-407b-af9b-80c81ef54746","substatus":65535}
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance,
Simone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format is not a valid Cosmos DB stored procedure format.

It should look like this:

```
function helloWorldStoredProc() {
    var context = getContext();
    var response = context.getResponse();

    response.setBody("Hello, World");
}
```

Here is the executed sample code:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The sample I posted is from MSDN.